# Phone navigation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am using a simple toggle to open and close my mobile navigation. When the navigation loads is loads the phone width and show the nav when is should be hidden causing the page to load wider than the width. Plus I can't get the Nav Menu to stay on the page so when it gets clicked again it will close.

Here is what I have and I am not sure why the nav is showing then it has not been clicked.

```
 #nav-ph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-btn-ph {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-btn-ph img {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 13px;
}
.main-nav-ph li {
    padding:0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: @m;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.main-nav-ph li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-nav-ph li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

$(function() {
    $('#nav-ph').stop().animate({'margin-right':'-300px'},1000);

    function toggleDivs() {
        var $inner = $("#nav-ph");
        if ($inner.css("margin-right") == "-300px") {
            $inner.animate({'margin-right': '0'});
            $(".nav-btn-ph").html()
        } else {
            $inner.animate({'margin-right': "-300px"}); 
            $(".nav-btn-ph").html()
        }
    }
    $(".nav-btn-ph").bind("click", function(){
        toggleDivs();
    });
});

<div id="nav-ph">
    <div class="nav-btn-ph">Nav Menu</div>
    <ul class="main-nav-ph">
        <li><a href="#the-banner-advantage">THE ADVANTAGE</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#banner-services">OUR SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">OUR TEAM</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#banner-news">MAKING NEWS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#banner-contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BrentRansom/vb3v5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, try to remove the following items

```
.nav-btn-ph {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -40px; //remove this css, the nav emnu will stay longer
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

better remove this animation code to stay within the margin

```
$('#nav-ph').stop().animate({'margin-right':'-300px'},1000);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vb3v5/3/)

Comment: Removing the left: -40px worked for the nav staying on the page to the left but the main problem I am having is on mobile when you close the menu the menu goes out side the page so you can move the page right and see the menu on mobile. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: What I would like to do is when the nav is closed I want to hide the links so they do not show up.

Comment: @user2836519 Not sure about mobile, but for your second item check this http://jsfiddle.net/vb3v5/4/

Comment: It is getting close but I would need the nav to slide from right to left and be closed when the page is loaded. Thanks for the helps so far.

Comment: I did a little tweaking but what you showed me worked. Thanks here is a link to the final [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BrentRansom/vb3v5/6/)

Comment: @user2836519 Glad that I was able to contribute.  Thanks for sharing the final fiddle